# How to find channels in a category by category name

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to find channels in a category by their names.
I've tried this method, but it didn't work.

```
category.channels.find(c => c.name == "Name" && c.type == "text");
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Any code you can show ?

Comment: `category.channels.find(c => c.name == "Name" && c.type == "text");`

Comment: you should inclued everything that is important in the question, not comments so new people will find everything they need to help you quicker !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the [`CategoryChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CategoryChannel?scrollTo=children) documentation, you can see that the attribute to get the channels of a category is actually `children`.

Try the following instead :

```js
category.children.find(c => c.name == "Name" && c.type == "text");
```

Comment: Ooooh thaaanks ^-^